# Django IN Query with different values of combination of two columns

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have to filter user from different city and state combination like
Users from cities [[Mumbai,MH],[Ahmedabad,GJ],...]

Where city = Mumbai and state = MH

This is what i am doing now

```
 users = cls.objects.annotate(unique_city=ExpressionWrapper(Concat(F('city'),F('state'),output_field=CharField()), output_field=CharField())).filter(unique_city__in = city_list)
```

where city_list = [MumbaiMH,AhemadabadGj,...]
Is there is a better way to do this

I have user model with field state and city

And city model with field state and city(unique together)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) instead.

Given a list of tuples `searchlist = [(city1, state1), (city2, state2), ...]`

```
if len( searchlist) == 0:
    query = cls.objects.none()

else:
    city, xstate = searchlist[0]
    q = Q( city=city, state=xstate)

    for city, xstate in searchlist[1:] :
         q = q | Q( city=city, state=xstate)

    query = cls.objects.filter( q)
```

Note: using `xstate` not `state` because SO auto-colorizing is doing really wierd things if I use state. It thinks its a reserved word, although in Python it's not?

Comment: I know about Q but wasn't very sure how to use it in this scenario(New to Django :) )can you also explain the difference between your and mine query performance wise?

Comment: @Sagar Gupta No! I would be interested to know. Almost included in my answer that I think mine looks cleaner, but might be less efficient SQL, especially for a long searchlist.

Comment: @Sagar_Gupta I can recommend installing django-debug-toolbar, then you can very easily see how long the SQL took for each query, and what SQL it generated.